# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'take'

Tags: python, pandas

```
# Preprocessing: Drop unnecessary columns and handle missing values
features = final_data.drop(['label'], axis=1)
labels = final_data['label']

# Split the dataset into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
```

[image]

I'm trying to build a GCN using a bipartite graph for attack prediction. I'm not sure what I need to do further. Can anyone help me to resolve this error?

Comment: Don't just post a link to your entire project. Isolate the relevant code and post that **in your question** along with an explanation of the circumstances that lead to the failure. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: It's hard to answer this question because you have not shown us a **complete** example.  What is `final_data`?  We can guess it is a dataframe, but what are its contents?  What columns does it have?

Comment: I have solved this issue but encountered another error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to know with the example you provided, but it's telling you that the dataframe doesn't contain a column named "take"

Use <your_df>.columns to check the correct naming